# App distribution to Crashlytics Beta doesn't work for Release version of my app

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

I'm trying to set up crashlytics beta app distribution process.

I have two schemes of building develop-variant of our app: `rocket:myapp_developDebug` and `rocket:myapp_developRelease` (names slightly changed). I have them both built and located in same output dir.

If I run `rocket:crashlyticsUploadDistributionMyapp_developDebug`, everything is ok and I see that distribution on Crashlytics Beta page. But for `rocket:crashlyticsUploadDistributionMyapp_developRelease` it succesfully finishes 'build', but app doesn't get its way to Beta.

From its message `Uploading /path/to/project/proj.android-studio/app/build/outputs/apk/rocket-myapp_develop-release.apk to Crashlytics...` it's clear that I have that apk; also it is really being uploaded (based on time and network load). The version itself is recognized by Crashlytics (on versions page).

What am I missing?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here - do you see both of the apps in the Fabric dashboard?

Comment: @MikeBonnell , Hi. Those are not two applications, they share their name (e.g. com.foobar.dev), but they're built with debug enabled/disabled. So no, there is only one application.